# Cardinality of the set of all the subsets of $X$ which have cardinality less than $|X|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Let $X$ be an infinite set of cardinality $|X|=\kappa$, and let $\mathcal{P}_{< \kappa}(X)$ be the set of all subsets $S$ of $X$ such that $|S| < \kappa$.

Is it true that $|\mathcal{P}_{< \kappa}(X)| < 2^{\kappa}$?

I do not know the anser to the question, and any idea is welcome.

Thank you very very much in advance for your help.

NB. I have an elementary knowledge of set theory. All that I know about this issue is what I found stated and proved in Jech, Set Theory, Third Millenium Edition, pp. 51- 52:
\begin{equation}
| \mathcal{P}_{< \kappa}(X) | = \kappa^{< \kappa},
\end{equation}
where $\kappa^{< \kappa}$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
\kappa^{< \kappa}= \sup \{ \kappa^{\mu}: \mu \textrm{ is a cardinal and } \mu < \kappa \}.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s consistent that $2^\omega=2^{\omega_1}$, so that $2^{\omega_1}=2^\omega\le\omega_1^\omega\le\omega_1^{\omega_1}=2^{\omega_1}$, and in that case

$$|\wp_{<\omega_1}(\omega_1)|=\omega_1^{\omega}=2^{\omega_1}\;.$$

Comment: Dear Brian, thank you very very ... much for having posted this simple and beautiful solution! If I do not bother you too much I would like to know some book or article where I could find a proof of the consistency of $2^{\omega}=2^{\omega_1}$. Thank you very much in advance again!!!

Comment: @MaurizioBarbato: You’re very welcome. It’s been a *very* long time since I looked at consistency proofs, so I can’t give you specific references, but I do know that this result follows from the consistency of Martin’s axiom plus the negation of the continuum hypothesis (e.g., Corollary 9.23 in [these notes](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/geschke/teaching/ModelsSetTheory.pdf) [PDF], or, by a different route, from [Easton’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem). I suspect that a simpler forcing argument suffices, but I don’t have a reference for one.

Comment: Dear Brian, I do not know how to thank you for your invaluable help and generosity for sharing with me and all the community your precious knowledge! I like so much set theory, which is a completely new field of mathematics for me, and I feel enthusiastic like a little baby which makes new discoveries every day! Thank you very very ... much again!

Comment: @Maurizio: You’re very welcome!